# 3RD LEVEL inline dropdown with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Kindly request a help to write 3-level inline dropdown menu using css.
As i have tried with java script/jquery.however it work for some time and dont get dropdown after some time.
 please go through the menu mostly "PACKAGES" and "FACILITIES" dropdown .

fYI:

Click here: http://www.fractaltree.in/works/native/

Comment: Try giving your each menu group a unique selector

Comment: @Godinall i have tried but not working. requestg css based dropdown...

Comment: what have your tried so far? can we have a http://www.jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @Scott http://jsfiddle.net/sofi02/Ykvkm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display your second level menu, you should use this selector

```
.droplinetabs li:hover > ul
```

Same concept for your third level menu.
You are messing up with selectors that's why you are having problem.

[HERE'S YOUR WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/Ykvkm/3/)

But honestly it would be better for your to learn how to make it then asking for a simple solution, that's why I only gave you a hint not a direct answer.

Comment: @godinail i want 3rd level to be aligned to 2nd level ie. to left http://jsfiddle.net/sofi02/Ykvkm/2/

Comment: @godinail ,Scott i want 3rd level to be aligned to 2nd level ie. to left http://nativeplace.com/testing/menu-17thapril14.html  or make it similar to  http://www.fractaltree.in/works/native/ if u can